# Generic Function with Delegate/Func

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

Hi I am trying to create a caching method that receive the request and a function in case there is nothing previously cached for the request, it would  execute the delegate function passed as a parameter.
I've been watching videos of Delegates and Funcs but the materials are always very basic and the return type of the delegate is strong type. I need something Generic to be used to different dtos (the object been cached).

I have some Customs Attribute decorating the ClasseDTOs I want to be caching  but this is working fine, so please ignore.

```
public async Task<AdministrationDashboardDto> GetAdministrationKPIsAsync()
{
    AdministrationDashboardDto dto = new AdministrationDashboardDto();

    var x = await TryGetInCacheAsync(dto, () => _iKpisService.GetAdministrationKPIsAsync());

    return (AdministrationDashboardDto)x;
}

private async Task<object> TryGetInCacheAsync<T>(object request, Func<T> p)
{
   var cacheQuery = request.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<CacheObjectAttribute>();
    if (cacheQuery != null)
    {
        var cacheKey = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheQuery.CacheKey)
            ? CacheHelper.GenerateCacheKeyFromRequest(dto)
            : cacheQuery.CacheKey;

        var cachedResponse = await _cacheService.GetCacheValueAsync(cacheKey);
        if (cachedResponse != null)
        {
            //_logger.LogInformation($"Request {typeof(TRequest).Name} served from cache");
            return cachedResponse;
        }

        var actualResponse = await Task.FromResult(p);
        await _cacheService.SetCacheValueAsync(cacheKey, actualResponse, cacheQuery.TimeSpanForCacheInvalidation);
        return actualResponse;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you just after `var actualResponse = p()`? You're creating a `Task<Func<T>>` where the `Task` has already completed, which seems pointless.

Comment: You're aiming to store a function in a cache? Why? What's the point?

Comment: @CaiusJard nops, the delegation function would be executed if the is nothing in the cache for that request. then the function would be executed getting the data from the source and added it in the cache for next times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the code is working fine, but the interfaces are the problem. You can get this to work, but not with the different types of the delegates and there return types.
 *Please note that maybe a different approach to what you are trying to achieve might be better but is out of scope now.

**Before I start my explanation, let me briefly summarize some critical details:**

- Interfaces are used to share a responsibility among classes, instances of these classes can be used in the same manner from the client point of view
- Delegates are simply interfaces for methods instead of classes

**To fix this issues, 2 steps need to be taken:**

- Create an interface for the different DTO's
- Create a delegate that returns this interface

So, given my conclusion of the problem domain is correct:

***note that I have not tested this, hope this gets you in the right direction**

```
    public interface DTO { }

    public class AdministrationDashboardDto : DTO {  }

    public delegate Task<DTO> GetDTO();

    public class TestClass
    {
        public async Task<DTO> GetAdministrationKPIsAsync()
        {
            AdministrationDashboardDto dto = new AdministrationDashboardDto();

            var x = await TryGetInCacheAsync(dto, () => _iKpisService.GetAdministrationKPIsAsync());

            return (AdministrationDashboardDto)x;

        }

        //PAY ATTENTION TO DELEGATE
        private async Task<DTO> TryGetInCacheAsync<T>(object request, GetDTO p)
        {
            var cacheQuery = request.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<CacheObjectAttribute>();
            if (cacheQuery != null)
            {
                var cacheKey = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheQuery.CacheKey)
                    ? CacheHelper.GenerateCacheKeyFromRequest(dto)
                    : cacheQuery.CacheKey;

                var cachedResponse = await _cacheService.GetCacheValueAsync(cacheKey);
                if (cachedResponse != null)
                {
                    //_logger.LogInformation($"Request {typeof(TRequest).Name} served from cache");
                    return cachedResponse;
                }

                //change to INVOKE METHOD ON DELEGATE
                var actualResponse = await p.Invoke();
                await _cacheService.SetCacheValueAsync(cacheKey, actualResponse, cacheQuery.TimeSpanForCacheInvalidation);
                return actualResponse;
            }

            return null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice idea. Worked nicely.

Comment: Thank you, glad I could help